# JAVA RSAES-OAEP attack

Tags: java, cryptography, encryption

I need to implement an RSAES-OAEP PKCS#1 V2.1 attack, using a unix executable oracle and a ASCII format challenge file. The format of challenge ASCII file is

```
{n}
{e}
{c}
```

where N (an integer) is a 1024-bit modulus, e (an integer) is the public exponent and c (an
octet string) is the ciphertext corresponding to the RSAES-OAEP encryption of some unknown
plaintext m (an octet string) under the public key (N, e). Note that the plaintext is ASCII text
(i.e., each octet is an ASCII encoded character), and that the RSAES-OAEP encryption will
have used SHA-1 as the hash function and a null label (i.e., in all cases the label is an octet
string of length zero).
The executable represents an RSAES-OAEP decryption oracle: when executed from a BASH
shell using the command

```
bash$ ./ USER < USER . challenge
```

it tries to decrypt the ciphertext read from stdin using the private key (N, d). Note that N is
read from stdin (i.e., from the challenge) but d (an integer) is a private exponent embedded
into the oracle (i.e., you do not have access to it).

The challenge file is as follows:

```
99046A2DB3D185D6D2728E799D66AC44F10DDAEE1C0A1AC5D7F34F04EDE17B96A5B486D95D927AA9B58FC91865DBF3A1685141345CC31B92E13F06E8212BAB22529F7D06B503AAFEEB89800E12EABA50C3F3BBE86F5966A88CCCF5C843281F8B98DF97A3111458FCA89B8085A96AE68EAEBAE270831D41C956159B81D29503
80A3C4043F940BE6AC16B11A0A77016DBA96B0239311AF182DD70E214E07E7DF3523CE1E269B176A3AAA0BA8F02C59262F693D6A248F22F2D561ED7ECC3CB9ABD0FE7B7393FA0A16C4D07181EEF6E27D97F48B83B90C58F51FD40DCDA71EF5E3C3E97D1697DC8E26B694B5CAFE59E427B12EE82A93064C81AAB74431F3A735
57D808889DE1417235C790CB7742EB76E537F55FD49941EBC862681735733F8BB095EDBB3C0DA44AB8F1176E69A61BBD3F0D31EB997071758A5DD850730A1D171E9EC92788EBA358974CE521537EE4A809BF1607D04EFD4A407866970981B88F44D5260D25C9E8864D5FC2AFB2CB90994DD1934BCEA728B38A00D4712AE0EE
```

Any ideas as to how to proceed for this attack?!

thanks
Anyone to guide me for this?!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: http://blog.gdssecurity.com/labs/2011/6/2/beyond-padding-oracle-mangers-oracle-and-rsa-oaep-padding.html

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you could try is to find out whether you can apply the attack by
J. Manger from the paper "A Chosen Ciphertext Attack on RSA Optimal Asymmetric Encryption
Padding (OAEP) as Standardized in PKCS #1 v2.0." Crypto 2001.

That means you have to find out what kind of information you can get from the oracle.
I.e. Choose two arbitrary integers m0, m1 such that m1 is a 1024-bit integer smaller than n
and m0 is 1023 or less bits long. If you pass m0^e mod n and m1^e mod n to the oracle do you get a different response? If so then you might be able to apply the attack in the paper above. Otherwise you will have to search for another flaw in the decryption oracle.

---

Another approach that might work is to try to modify the modulus n. If the oracle really reads the modulus from user supplied input, then it looks like modifying the modulus should work and the attack becomes quite easy. I don't have access to the implementation of the oracle so I can only guess what might be possible. If you can check for any chosen
n',c' whether c'^d mod n' is a valid OAEP encoded plaintext then you decrypting the original message is not all you can do, in fact you can also recover d and hence factor the original RSA modulus.

(Furthermore this would indeed be a very nice puzzle, so I don't want to spoil the fun by giving
a step by step receipe on how to solve it.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually its a coursework. And we have to implement an attack on RSA-OAEP and get the plaintext. If you want I can provide you the oracle and the the challenge text is already there in my question.  And trust me its not a fun for us :D ;)